# Is it possible to create your own custom font by using Java?

Tags: java, image, fonts

I have a font-made image and I'm curious, is it possible to convert it into real font in Java?
(e.g .ttf form). I don't find any "how to" for this.

Comment: what do you mean by convert it into real font, is it about create awt.Font ? or use an image like a font ? or convert it to a font file ?

Comment: Short answer would be no.  `ttf` is, essentially, vector based.

Comment: convert it to font file, is there any other way to convert it to real font?

Comment: @MadProgrammer actually the short answer would be "java's a programming language. Of course it's possible", but the long answer would involve writing a font generator, so...

Comment: If you just have a sheet and you want to turn it into a font, just use one of the many online "turn sheet into font" services.

Answer (score 0):

read this document i think it helps you.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/fonts.html